# Сравнение массивов на идентичность

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть такой дырявый код (цикл в цикле)..

```
    foreach($result as $r){
        foreach($ids_time as $time){
            if($r['id_time'] == $time['id']){
                $row[] = $r;
            }
        }           
    }
```

Нужно более по простому сделать сравнение и вывести значения массива $result у которых идентичны значения с массивом $ids_time как это делает подобный код.

Массив $ids_time такого вида

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 93
        [date] => 2017-03-31
    )
```

А массив $result такого вида

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 22
        [id_time] => 93
        [id_client] => 69
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если идентификаторы id уникальны, то вернее будет обойти оба массива по одному разу. Например, проиндексируйте массив $ids_time, а затем смапте id_time из $result в соответствующие значения:

```
function arr_index($arr, $key) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if (isset($item[$key])) {
            $result[$item[$key]] = $item;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$indexed_time = arr_index($ids_time, 'id');
$row = array_map(function($item) use($indexed_time) {
    return $indexed_time[$item['time_id']] ?? null;
}, $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать callback-функцию в `array_uintersect`. Но зачем? Есть вещи, которые не стоит усложнять. К сожалению, в данном примере массив многомерный, и красивого способа сравнения нет, поэтому лучше оставить как есть.

Answer (score 0):

Можно избавиться от вложенных циклов, если переписать код так:

```
$timesId = [];
foreach ($ids_time as $time) {
    $timesId[$time['id']] = $time['id'];
}
foreach ($result as $r) {
    if (!empty($timesId[$r['id_time']])) {
        $row[] = $r;
    }
}
```

Это немного упростит восприятие и сопровождение кода, но отъест памяти на временную переменную.

Если `id` у времени - уникальное поле, то можно использовать его в качестве ключа в массиве и тогда останется только проверять наличие таких ключей - без временного массива и без вложенного цикла. Но для этого надо больше деталей о ваших данных, которыми вы оперируете. Так с ходу не сказать. Например, если они (данные) изначально лежали в базе, то может решить проблему можно ещё на этапе выборки, переписав запрос, и не мучиться потом с массивами в коде.

Answer (score 0):

Если ключи в `$result` следуют по порядку то можно использовать `array_search`
(если не по порядку, то можно предварительно переиндексировать через `array_values`) Для больших массивов это будет быстрее. Но надо учесть, что `array_search` возвращает ключ только первого найденного элемента.

```html
$arr1 = array_column($ids_time, 'id');
$arr2 = array_column($result, 'id_time');
foreach ($arr1 as $value) {
    $key = array_search($value, $arr2);
    if ($key !== false) {
        $row[] = $result[$key];
    }
}
```